# FatalExecutionEngineError when importing C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wcf

I have written an application which calls methods from a dll written in C++. It is a WinForms application, which has a WCF service self-hosted in it. One of the WCF methods is
called in 2-3 seconds periodically. The problem does not occur when only the WCF part is executed. The problem does no appear when only the SDK functions are called. However if
I start the WCF client which calls my method periodically, and the same time I execute some SDK functions, after 10 seconds a FatalExecutionEngineError (System.ExecutionEngineException).
exception is raised and the application crashes. I really don't know what could be the problem, or how to solve it. I suspect it is somehow related with the SDK, but I'm not sure, just a 
feeling. Reading the related answers here in SO, maybe the method-imports are wrong? Here is what I got so far:

WCF class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial interface IWCFSample
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(string param);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public partial class WCFSample : IWCFSample
{
    #region Delegates

    public delegate string OnGetDataDelegate(object sender, string getDataParam);

    #endregion Delegates

    #region Events

    public event OnGetDataDelegate OnGetData;

    #endregion Events

    public string GetData(string serializedGetDataParam)
    {
        string res = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (OnGetData != null)
            {
                res = OnGetData(this, (serializedGetDataParam));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Initiated like this:

```
    private ServiceHost _serviceHost;
    private WCFSample _samplewcf;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _samplewcf = new WCFSample();
        _samplewcf.OnGetData += samplewcfOnGetData;

        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_samplewcf);
        _serviceHost.Open();
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        bw.DoWork += (o, args) =>
        {
            WCFSampleClient client = new WCFSampleClient();
            while (true)
            {
                if (bw.CancellationPending)
                {
                    return;
                }

                client.GetData(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private string samplewcfOnGetData(object sender, string getDataParam)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "GetData Called - " + getDataParam + "\n";
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        return getDataParam;
    }
```

The C++ related parts are pretty long, but here are the imports I use.

```
int OpenDevice (char* strUSBName, int iPortNum )

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int OpenDevice(string USBNam, int portnum);


int CheckFeeder (int* nCheck)

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int CheckFeeder(ref int pStatus);


int DP_GetSensorStatus (BYTE *pRailStatus, BYTE *pFeedRollerStatus, BYTE *pTraySensorState)

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int DP_GetSensorStatus(ref byte pRailStatus, ref byte pFeedRollerStatus, byte[] pTraySensorState);


int PathSenser(int *pStatus)

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int PathSenser(ref int p1);


int CheckRibbonEx( int *nRibbon, int *nTagRibbon)

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int CheckRibbonEx(ref int nRibbon, ref int nTagRibbon);


int N_EndOfPrint(int nPanel, int *pPanelCount, int *pJobNo)

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int N_EndOfPrint(int p1, ref int p2, ref int p3);


int N_PrintJobStatus (int *pJobStatus )

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int N_PrintJobStatus(int[] p1);
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the last import is wrong:

```
int N_PrintJobStatus (int *pJobStatus )

Imported as:
[DllImport("TP9000.dll")]
public static extern int N_PrintJobStatus(int[] p1);
```

If I don't call this function in my code, it does not hang. But how should I marshal it. The documentation says:

> It checks the status of the printing.
>
> int N_PrintJobStatus (int *pJobStatus )
>   Parameter pJobStatus[out]:
>
> - JobStatus[0] = Priter Status : idle(0x00), in printing(0x01),    Error-Printing Stop(0xFF)
> - JobStatus[1] = No Standby Job (on Error, No    pausing Job)
> - JobStatus[2] = the number of standby job (including the    currently operating job)
> - JobStatus[3] = the number of copies of the    currently operating job(total number of printing copies)
> - JobStatus[4] = the number of copies of the remaining jobs (Remaining Count)
> - JobStatus[5] = if the re-printig checking window displays or not.  1: AUTO Option display, 2:Manual option display, 0: No Checking Window
> - JobStatus[6] = it checks the error processing and status message    level (1~4) then show 0t at retprinting checking window(Auto Option)
>
>   1. Open the printer and then check the ribbon.
>   2. Card is ejecting
>   3. Ribbon is being synchronized
>   4. If you want to re-print, please press “OK” button.( make “OK” button activated)
>
> Return value 0: Success. -1: Failure. (Get_Status)

Comment: This is unrelated to the solution of your problem, but sometimes a `BackgroundWorker` just isn't the right tool for the job. Also: Why do you host a WCF service within your application and also *call* it from within your application? If it's all in the same application, just do your stuff directly.

Comment: This is just a test application, in the final version there is no backroundworker and the client/server applications are two separete executables. This app was created to easily reproduce the problem (which unfortunately succeeded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, without the rest of the code it was impossible to solve this. The **wrong code** was the following:

```
int[] nJobSt = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //notice that the array length is 6
LastErrorCode = TP9000Dll.N_PrintJobStatus(nJobSt);
```

From the SDK documentation we should assume the function needs an array length of 7
So the **correct code** is:

```
int[] nJobSt = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //notice that the array length is 7
LastErrorCode = TP9000Dll.N_PrintJobStatus(nJobSt);
```

The conclusion: Read every documentation 3 times, never trust the sample applications which are coming with the SDK.